# Send Intercom Message every time an event occurs?

Tags: intercom.js

Hi im trying to send messages through intercom every time an event is sent. Let's say i have a feature in my product which is submitting intercom events every time the user clicks a certain tab. I would like to send a message on every occur of the event. I have already set an auto message in my intercom app, but i´m just able to send the message the first time the event occurs.

Comment: would love to know this as well. is there any update since the API and app appears to be way more robust now?

Answer (score 2):

According to the interecom support team, auto-messaging is the currently the only way to do it. For now, they do not support advanced/customized triggers like "send the user a welcome message for the first 3 times when he clicks some link"